# C++ - Is possible to have subclass contain the containing class by value?

Tags: c++, subclass

```
class Containing{

    class Subclass{

        Containing cont;

    };

};
```

Currently this says "error: field cont has incomplete type". Is this not possible at all with C++? Or when someone needs this does it mean they have wrong program design? Should Subclass be a derived / separate class instead?

Comment: What's your target? Could you plz provide some more background? Don't get trapped in XY-problems.

Comment: @L.F. In the real program Containing would be a vector and Subclass would be a normalized vector as a special case. I was thinking about using inheritance or a separate NormalizedVector class, or this solution.

Comment: That's helpful info. In your case Normalized Vector should just be a separate class. (I smell the scent of XY :P)

Comment: You want your vector to be mutable I think? So inheritance is not a solution, because the type of your vector couldn't change when you normalize it.

Comment: @L.F. What is the sense when he can go to the instance of NormalizedVector and change a component to screw it?

Comment: @L.F. Thanks! What is "XY" if I may ask? One reason I wanted this solution is for better namings (Vector::NormalizedVector).

Comment: XY means your goal is X, you try to solve it by Y, but you don't know Y either, so you ask Y. However, actually Y may not be a suitable solution at all. See this: http://xyproblem.info/

Comment: I wanted the vector inside "NormalizedVector" to be const.

Comment: @Newline You can use namespaces for this purpose (naming).

Comment: It's not a subclass, it's a nested class. Worth knowing the correct lingo for searching purposes.

Comment: @StoryTeller Yes, sorry about that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the same problem as

```
class Containing; 
class Subclass 
{ 
    Containing cont; 
};
```

You can solve it in the same way as the non-nested problem, by defining the dependent class after the class it depends on.

```
class Containing
{
    class Subclass;
};

class Containing::Subclass
{
    Containing cont;
};
```

Comment: Thanks! This answers the question, though now I will have problems with Subclass being incomplete if I want to do anything with it in Containing (like even creating one and returning it).

Comment: @Newline - You should be able to organize the definitions of member function so the class is complete at every point. Though honestly, I think you may need to reconsider your design if that's an issue.

Comment: As soon as Containing has code handling type Subclass (except pointer), the size of Subclass will be needed when the compiler reads the definition of Containing, and since you only forward declared it, its unavailable. If it is inside a method, just put the definitions afterwards or in the .cpp-file. If it is a member variable of type Subclass this will not be possible anyhow.

Comment: @birdfreeyahoo - What are you on about? This is perfectly valid C++.

Comment: Yes sorry edited it. I don't mean your code, but if he wants to use Subclass in Containing

Comment: @birdfreeyahoo - The OP can do that too by carefully defining and placing the member functions in the correct order. Also, it's not *my answer*. I just passed by.

Comment: @StoryTeller Tell me how he can have an instance of Subclass (plain, no pointer) as member in Continaing. I cannot imagine that working. It needs the full declaration of Subclass and this needs the full declaration of Containing. Also what is sizeof(Containing) then? It needs to store a Subclass instance, which in turn needs to store a Containing instance and so on.

Comment: @birdfreeyahoo - Where on earth did the OP indicate they wanted a member of the nested class? C++ is not Java. The only relationship between these classes is lexical scoping.

Comment: @StoryTeller I only wrote that in case he wants a member variable, if he does anything other, he sure can define those methods after the declarations. But I thought your last comment refers to member variables, since I already admitted that everything else is possible with proper arrangement.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you want could be a pointer:

```
class Containing;

class Containing{

    class Subclass{

        Containing* cont;

    };

};
```

In Java, class instances are pointers by default. This means that this is just an address value which contains the address of the Containing object. So the cont is a separate instance which you refer to by the pointer. Your code doesn't work because the declaration of Containing isn't finished, thus Containing isn't known yet. It would need its own declaration to finish its own declaration.

What I did above the class is a forward declaration. This means I told the compiler that there is a class with the name Containing declared. Then you can use a pointer to Containing, because you don't have to know anything about the members or the size of Containing.

Be aware, that you by default have no pointer, you first need an instance of Subclass, maybe this is even what you want:

```
class Containing;

class Containing{
    Containing* cont;
};
```